# disable jshint for project using Sublime 3

Tags: sublimetext3, jshint, sublimelinter

I have a project in which I'm using standard as the default linter, according to sublimeLinter documentation y need to create a `.sublime-project` file with the following info:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "SublimeLinter":
    {
        "linters":
        {
            "jshint": {
                "disable": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

however this isn't working, I've tried using both `disable` and `@disable`, created a `.sublimelinterrc` file with the same info, also tried with a `.sublime-workspace`file, didn't worked, created a `.jshintignore`... didnt work.

Until now, the only thing that has worked is using this line in top of the file `// jshint ignore: start` but I don't want to write this in every single file, I want to disable it for all the project. Any idea of how can I do it?

Comment: Possibly silly question, but do you have the project loaded or is the file just present inside one of the folders?

Comment: I think i just have it on the folder, how am I supposed to load it?

Comment: Select `Project > Open Project` to create a new window with that project loaded in it so that you can see how things work. If that fixes things go back to your initial window and select `Project > Save Project`, then `Project > Edit Project` to make the same changes to it; that will allow you to retain the same layout as you're currently using while still using the project.

Comment: That did it, thank you so much, guess I wasn't loading the project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [OdatNurd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/814803/odatnurd) the file won't do nothing by itself, it has to be loaded through the sublime project option in menu.

Answer (score 1):

There is a newer, easier syntax for this. In your sublime project file add the following under settings.

```
{
    "settings":
    {
        "SublimeLinter.linters.jshint.disable": true
    }
}
```